# How to load an Idris file that depends on a package?

Tags: spacemacs, major-mode, repl, ide, load

Working in Spacemacs (on Linux Mint, if that is relevant), using the Idris layer, one of my major mode commands is `SPC m-r` (Vim-style keybindings): `idris-load-file`. This causes Spacemacs to load up an Idris REPL instance and use it to type check the file. Once the REPL is loaded, other IDE-like functionality is enabled such as split case, proof search, etc. Thus the ability to load the file is crucial for smooth Idris development.

Idris has the concept of a *package*; for example, if you want a set implementation, there is one in the `contrib` package. Thus, for example, this code depends on `contrib`:

```
module NeedsContrib

import Data.SortedSet

foo : SortedSet Int -> Maybe Int
```

If I try to load this code in the Idris REPL outside Spacemacs, I must provide the `-p contrib` command-line argument. If I do not, I get `Can't find import Data/SortedSet`. In my Vim development workflow, I launch Idris myself, manually, so I am able to specify this argument and it works. However, in Spacemacs' fancy way of doing things, it loads the Idris process itself, and I do not know how to indicate to it that I need `contrib` - I get `Can't find import Data/SortedSet` in the errors window, indicating the REPL has been loaded without `-p contrib`.

When I write much serious Idris code at all, I almost always end up using `contrib`, or other packages. I would really like to transition from using Vim to Spacemacs for Idris development but this is hanging me up.

How do I get Spacemacs to launch the Idris process with the appropriate `-p <package>` argument as necessary, or perhaps to connect to an existing running Idris instance with the arguments that I have already supplied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layer for idris in Spacemacs use this `https://github.com/idris-hackers/idris-mode`.

So for my part, using spacemacs and helm, I succesfully load a file using contrib using the following shortcut:

- <kbd>SP</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>
- `idris-set-idris-load-packages` + <kbd>RET</kbd>
- `contrib` + `RET`
- <kbd>CTR</kbd> + <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Worked great. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After trying @luc-duzan's answer, Spacemacs prompted me for whether to persist the setting. When I selected yes, the following was added to my buffer:

```
-- Local Variables:
-- idris-load-packages: ("contrib")
-- End:
```

Sure enough, this caused it to work after closing and re-opening Spacemacs, without going back through the steps. It's a bit of noise added to the buffer, but perhaps useful nonetheless.